# Passing File Name to Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, export, procedure

I'm trying to write a **Procedure** that dumps into a file data for a specific *userid* that is stored as *integer* number. I want that the output file name contains the **userid** number as reference using the following SQL statement:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE Export_Test 
(
   UID int(11)
) 
BEGIN 
SET @OutputFile:=CONCAT('/output_UID',UID,'.csv');
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE user_id =UID INTO OUTFILE @OutputFile FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '';
END 
//
delimiter ;
```

However I always got a *Syntax Error close to "@OutputFile FIELDS..."* but I cannot figure out what's wrong. 
I'm using **MySQL Server** version is **5.6.17** and trying to create the query in  **phpMyAdmin** **4.6.2**.
Any clue?

---

NOTE: This question is different from *[Can I use a variable to specify OUTPUT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548118/can-i-use-a-variable-to-specify-outfile-in-mysql)* as this time I'm using a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I use a variable to specify OUTFILE in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548118/can-i-use-a-variable-to-specify-outfile-in-mysql)

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13870

Comment: The question was more complex as it was involving local variables and external params. I've learned about the bug and wondering how nobody tried to fix it yet. So the final look of the above sql statement becomes: `delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE Export_DATA 
(
   DID int(11)
) 
BEGIN 
SET @sql_text = 
    CONCAT (
       "SELECT * FROM data WHERE device_id=",DID," INTO OUTFILE '/EXPORT"
       ,"_",DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d'),"-",LPAD(DID, 5, '0'),".csv'"
    );
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
END
//
delimiter ;`

Comment: People are busy, it is the summer, and you had 10 page views.

Comment: The stored procedure is irrelevant. It's the same problem and the same solution.

Comment: Thank You @shmosel: I misunderstood _sami_ reply in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548118/can-i-use-a-variable-to-specify-outfile-in-mysql. I wrongly guessed the limitation was not present in Stored Procedure. I'm wondering why nobody made a fix for this.