# MySQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE variable outpath

Tags: mysql

I need to execute a query multiple times with different variables and redirect the output into an output file defined in a variable.

I am trying something like

```
SET @OUTFILE = '/tmp/outfile_1';
select  *
from db
INTO OUTFILE @OUTFILE;
```

but I have the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@OUTFILE'
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548118/can-i-use-a-variable-to-specify-outfile-in-mysql

Comment: In my environment it would be too much complicated to modify all the queries in the way explained in your link. I am wondering  if someone has an idea on how to adapt my code (if it is possible!) @N00bPr0grammer

Comment: What you need to do is what is illustrated @AlessandroBlasetti!