# How to use a variable value in a query

Tags: mysql, variables, mysql-workbench

As shown in the code below I want to export my tables to the location in 'secure_file_priv', as it is I just manually copy and paste it but I'd like to be able to just use it's value.

```
USE Library;


show VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';

set mylocation := (VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv');

SELECT 'Id', 'Name', 'Birthplace', 'Birthday', 'Gender'
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Name, Birthplace, Birthday, Gender
    FROM Author
    INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/author.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Instead of manually writing '/var/lib/mysql-files/author.csv' I'd like to be able to use the 'secure_file_priv' variable's value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I use a variable to specify OUTFILE in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548118/can-i-use-a-variable-to-specify-outfile-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @mylocation = (SELECT @@secure_file_priv);

SELECT 'Id', 'Name', 'Birthplace', 'Birthday', 'Gender'
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Name, Birthplace, Birthday, Gender
    FROM Author
    INTO OUTFILE @mylocation
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```